# Triple Data Encryption Standard

Tags: encryption, 3des

[image]

Based on this, it looks like something slightly wrong. What would need to be adjusted at the transmitter side to allow the receiver to decrypt the message/data?

Comment: A better question might be: "I don't understand this because ..." instead of something is wrong. What part do you not understand?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong. This is 3DES with two keys.

The Decryption operation precisely undoes the Encryption operation.

The right E in Encryption is undone by the left D in Decryption, the middle D in Encryption is undone by the middle E in Decryption, the left E in Encryption is undone by the right D in Decryption.

For a rigorous proof that using D in the encryption still allows decryption, see [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/55002/555). For an explanation of why the D in the encryption, see [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/2061/555). These are for 3DES with 3 keys, but the reasoning applies to 2 keys as well.

Comment: The answer might be better if why EDE/DED was chosen and not EEE/DDD. The D in encrypt and E in decrypt might be what the OP is concerned about.

Comment: @zaph: if so they could look at https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2060/why-do-we-use-encrypt-decrypt-encrypt-ede-in-3des-rather-than- (and several others linked to it)