# Encryption-Decryption-Encryption

Tags: multiple-encryption

I have learned from Applied Cryptography that triple encryption with three independent keys in encryption-decryption-encryption (EDE) process gives security not higher then $2^{2n}$ when it comes to meet-in-the-middle attack, where $n$ is keysize. If the triple encryption is done in encryption-encryption-encryption (EEE) process instead, is the security still the same as in EDE process or less?

I'm just curious to know how and how much security does this middle decryption provide?

Comment: Related: [Why do we use encrypt-decrypt-encrypt (EDE) in 3DES, rather than encrypting three times?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2060/why-do-we-use-encrypt-decrypt-encrypt-ede-in-3des-rather-than-encrypting-thre)

Comment: This isn't quite a duplicate, however a related question (specific to DES) is http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2060/why-do-we-use-encrypt-decrypt-encrypt-ede-in-3des-rather-than-encrypting-thre/2061#2061

Comment: @poncho 20 seconds too slow :)

Comment: @CodesInChaos: hey, if I hadn't bothered typing in all of "This isn't a quite a duplicate...", I would have been first :-)

Comment: thnaks pancho for your answer in the related question it cleared a lot :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EEE and EDE are effectively the same in terms of security.  EDE is used because it is "backwards compatible:" by setting all three keys to be the same, it becomes equivalent to just single encryption (E) with that key.