# How to make DES more secure without switching from des state to another cryptography system and what are limitations of DES?

Tags: des, 3des, desx

How to make DES more secure without switching from des state to another cryptography system and what are limitations of DES?
Is there any 3 ways to make des more secure?

Answer (score 2):

Arguably the most serious security issues with DES is it's small key of 8 bytes with only $2^{56}$ effective keys¹, which makes it vulnerable to brute force key search. This is a [deliberate design choice](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/34228/555).

A standard way to improve on this issue while still using DES is [TDEA](https://csrc.nist.gov/csrc/media/publications/fips/46/3/archive/1999-10-25/documents/fips46-3.pdf#page=20), also known as 3DES. The key is extended to 2 or 3 keys of 8 bytes $(K_1,K_2)$ or $(K_1,K_2,K_3)$. These modes are designated TDEA with keying option 2 (16-byte key) and keying option 1 (24-byte key). Encryption of an 8-byte plaintext block $P$ or ciphertext block $C$ becomes
$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{TDEA-ENC}_{(K_1,K_2)}(P)&\underset{\text{def}}=\operatorname{DES-ENC}_{K_1}(\operatorname{DES-DEC}_{K_2}(\operatorname{DES-ENC}_{K_1}(P)))\\
\operatorname{TDEA-DEC}_{(K_1,K_2)}(C)&\underset{\text{def}}=\operatorname{DES-DEC}_{K_1}(\operatorname{DES-ENC}_{K_2}(\operatorname{DES-DEC}_{K_1}(C)))\\
\operatorname{TDEA-ENC}_{(K_1,K_2,K_3)}(P)&\underset{\text{def}}=\operatorname{DES-ENC}_{K_3}(\operatorname{DES-DEC}_{K_2}(\operatorname{DES-ENC}_{K_1}(P)))\\
\operatorname{TDEA-DEC}_{(K_1,K_2,K_3)}(C)&\underset{\text{def}}=\operatorname{DES-DEC}_{K_1}(\operatorname{DES-ENC}_{K_2}(\operatorname{DES-DEC}_{K_3}(C)))\\
\end{align}$$

That largely solves the issue of brute force key search, which becomes economically infeasible for 24-byte keys, and [arguably](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/85576/555) still for 16-byte keys. The next worrying issues become

1. The small 8-byte block size of 64 bit, which is an issue when the amount of data encrypted with the same key is in gigabytes.
2. Low speed, worsened by a factor close to three by using TDEA/3DES.
3. Side channel and fault attacks.
4. The complementation property: $\operatorname{DES-ENC}_{\overline K}(\overline P)=\overline{\operatorname{DES-ENC}_K(P)}$, which also applies to TDEA/3DES.

While there are solutions to 1 and even 4 usign DES as a building block, those that are secure are complex, seriously worsen 2, and are not standardized. I'd recommend to go [AES](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/fips/nist.fips.197.pdf) or [ChaCha](https://cr.yp.to/chacha.html).

---

In order to improve on 2, Ronald Rivest proposed DESX, an alternative to TDEA/3DES. It's studied by Joe Killian and Phillip Rogaway: [How to Protect DES Against Exhaustive Key Search](https://www.cs.ucdavis.edu/%7Erogaway/papers/desx.pdf), in [proceedings of Crypto 1996](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-68697-5_20) then [Journal of Cryptology (2001)](https://doi.org/10.1007/s001450010015). It's defined by
$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{DESX-ENC}_{(K,K_1)}(P)&\underset{\text{def}}=K_1\oplus \operatorname{DES-ENC}_K(K_1\oplus P)\\
\operatorname{DESX-DEC}_{(K,K_1)}(C)&\underset{\text{def}}=K_1\oplus \operatorname{DES-DEC}_K(K_1\oplus C)\\
\operatorname{DESX-ENC}_{(K,K_1,K_2)}(P)&\underset{\text{def}}=K_2\oplus \operatorname{DES-ENC}_K(K_1\oplus P)\\
\operatorname{DESX-DEC}_{(K,K_1,K_2)}(C)&\underset{\text{def}}=K_1\oplus \operatorname{DES-DEC}_K(K_2\oplus C)\\
\end{align}$$
It largely has the advantages of TDEA/3DES in term of resistance to strictly brute-force key search, with very little extra cost compared to DES. However some caveats apply, as this construction (now known as the FX construction when generically applied to a block cipher) allows  specific time-memory tradeoffs, see Itai Dinur, [Cryptanalytic Time-Memory-Data Tradeoffs for FX-Constructions with Applications to PRINCE and PRIDE](https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/656.pdf), in [proceedings of Eurocrypt 2015](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-662-46800-5_10); and it's references.

---

¹ Down to $2^{55}$ when the complementation property applies, which includes chosen plaintext attack.

Comment: I understood that using triple DES could make DES more secure. Also, does another variants of DES, called DESX and GDES technique could also make des more secure?

Comment: @ehk: I choose not to mention GDES, because it does not use DES as a building block (rather, it's a wider cipher reusing the DES round function), was broken early on (see Eli Biham & Adi Shamir's [Differential cryptanalysis of DES-like cryptosystem](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00630563)), and contrary to TDEA/3DES and DESX has no significant industry use AFAIK.