# triple-des simple questtion

Tags: des

[Why do we use encrypt-decrypt-encrypt (EDE) in 3DES, rather than encrypting three times?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2060/why-do-we-use-encrypt-decrypt-encrypt-ede-in-3des-rather-than-encrypting-thre/2061#2061)

in this link, we use EDE Mode usually.

when we use one key, in this case, Encryption -> Decryption result will be Plain text. so as a result, we just do one DES encryption.

and other case, we use two key, (k1-k2-k1) or three keys, in this case each result of E D E will different, so there is no vulnerability use 'EDE' or 'EEE'.

http://des.online-domain-tools.com/ in this site we can do DES encryption or decryption, and i test all case refer above.

1. encrypt `test`. it is EDE 's first 'E'.
   [image: encrypt 'test']
2. decrypt `encrypted test`. it is EDE 's middle 'D'.
   [image: decrypt 'test']
   as you can see, the result is plain text.

I know that i am newbie and this article is wrong. but i can't understand why we use EDE and which part i missed.

thanks for your help :)

---

in single key, EEE mode. encrypt `encrypted test`. it is EEE 's middle 'E'
[image]
result of EEE's middle 'E' is not plaintext. so EEE isn't just do one time DES algorithm.

Comment: One single library to rule them all- no need to separate library if you need to support the DES.

Comment: Dear new user, we're saying that EDE with a single key for each E and D is single DES, not EEE. This is considered a good thing as you can *deliberately* get single DES. Of course, if you chose the 3 keys randomly than the chance of choosing such a EDE *weak key* are abysmally small (this on confusion in the edit description).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes hi, i'm completely understand this problem. but have one question. in EDE k1 k2 k1 mode(1,3 key is same), how can we make des structure? i think find `reverse of encrypt key`(because encrypt - decrypt is plaintext) is np problem. is it possible?

Comment: You simply set k1 to the same value as k2? Then k1, k2 and k3 are the same as k2 = k3 is implied.