# Triple DES 1 key to simulate 3 keys

Tags: 3des

I saw a statement that the probability of finding a key $k'$ to simulate 3 keys $k_1$, $k_2$, $k_3$ is neglectable: $\mathrm{Enc}(k_3,\mathrm{Enc}(k_2,\mathrm{Enc}(k_1,x))) = \mathrm{Enc}(k′,x)$

When not considering MITM attack, the probability of brute forcing triple DES is $1/2^{168}$.
According to the statement, does that mean the probability of finding $k'$ is also $1/2^{168}$ so it is negligible? Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: It's "negligible", please see [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/202832/is-there-a-difference-between-negligible-and-neglectable) for a discussion on the subject.

Comment: Triple DES is usually defined as $\operatorname{Enc}(k_3,\operatorname{Dec}(k_2,\operatorname{Enc}(k_1,x)))$, see [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/2060/555). Independently: quoting the statement or linking to it would be useful. It's so easy to twist a statement when restating it! For example "probability of finding" is not the same as "probability that there exists", and depends on the effort made. Probability of brute forcing triple DES _by trying a random key in a known-plaintext scenario_ is $1/2^{168}$, but without the extra detail the statement is too vague to be falsifiable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. In the triple encryption case, we expect that the chance of such a key existing at all is about $2^{56}/64!\approx 2^{-240}$ (assuming a 64-bit block size and 56-bit single key space). There's no particular structure that should make is treat the $2^{168}$ permutations corresponding to the different possible possible choices of 3 keys as anything other than a random permutation, likewise for the $2^{56}$ permutations corresponding to a single encryption.

(ETA: Poncho points out that there is some structure for [four known DES keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard#Minor_cryptanalytic_properties) for which encryption and decryption are the same. In the case, where $k_2$ is such a key and either $k_1$ or $k_2$ is also, then the triple encryption is equivalent to a single key encryption. This happens with probability roughly $2^{-109}$. There are also [six pairs of semi-weak keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard#Minor_cryptanalytic_properties) where encryption without one is the same as decryption with another, again if $k_2$ belongs to one of these pairs and either $k_1$ or $k_2$ then there is single key equivlance. This has additional probability roughly $2^{-107.4}$)

However, *[triple DES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES)* is not threefold encryption but rather DES-encryption with one key $k_1$, DES-decryption with another key $k_2$ and DES-encryption with a third key $k_3$. In the case $k_1=k_2$ this structure is equivalent to single DES-encryption with $k_3$ and in the case $k_2=k_3$ it is equivalent to single DES-encryption with $k_1$. If $k_1,k_2,k_3$ are chosen independently, uniformly at random the chance of one of these two occurrences is about $2^{-55}$, and as before we expect other triples to correspond to single keys with probability $2^{56}/64!$.

If there is an equivalent single key, we expect to be able to find it with $2^{56}$ work and one or two matched plain and cipher pairs. We do this just be exhausting the single key space. The chance of a false positive on one matched pair is about $2^{-8}$ and on two matched pairs is about $2^{-72}$.

Comment: Actually, DES has weak (self-inverse) keys.  In the triple encryption case, this allows some 3DES/DES equivalent keys; if either the first two DES keys or the last two keys are the same weak key, then the entire 3DES structure is the same as the remaining DES key - there are four weak keys, and so this leads to a probability circa $2^{-109}$

Comment: @poncho Good catch; now edited to add. There's even more chance of pathology from semi-weak keys.